# Capitalize All First Letter in a Word in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Anyone knows how to do it?

So we split that based on space, and then capitalize each, and then move them back right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either of these methods to accomplish that:

[`-[NSString capitalizedString]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/capitalizedString)

Or:

[`-[NSString capitalizedStringWithLocale:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/capitalizedStringWithLocale%3a)

Comment: NSString ain't a namespace.

Comment: @CodaFi Forgive the poor PHP dev ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [`capitalizedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-capitalizedString) method.

> **Return Value**
>
> A string with the first character from each word in the receiver changed to its corresponding uppercase value, and all remaining characters set to their corresponding lowercase values.

Answer (score 2):

To capitalize use :

```
string=[string capitalizedString];
```

Gives each word of the sentence in capital.

---

> So we split that based on space, and then capitalize each, and then
>   move them back right?

This is not required. No need to break in words and individually capitalize each one of them.

Comment: @Sunny: but You get more upvotes only when other answers aren't from big celebrities :p